# How to apply Pandas Groupby with multiple conditions for split and apply multiple calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe that I need to split based on 2 conditions and this conditions applied to 3 different columns, then using those new splits perform some calculations on other columns in a pairwise manner.

So I have a df A

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1], [3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4], [4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5], [5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1]],
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I need to split the dataframe based on 2 conditions and applied to the first three columns, like this"

```
condition1_colA = A[A['A'] > 1]
condition2_colA = A[A['A'] < 1]
condition1_colB = A[A['B'] > 1]
condition2_colB = A[A['B'] < 1]
condition1_colC = A[A['C'] > 1]
condition2_colC = A[A['C'] < 1]
```

Now, I need to do 3 calculations on each of 6 new sliced dataframes, however this calculations are paired up in the following way:

- condition1_colA and condition2_colA with column['D']
- condition1_colB and condition2_colB with column['E']
- condition1_colC and condition2_colC with column['F']

Here would be the example for the first pair:

```
x = condition1_colA['D'].mean()
y = condition1_colA['D'].std()
z = condition1_colA['D'][condition1_colA['D'] > 0].count()
x1 = condition2_colA['D'].mean()
y1 = condition2_colA['D'].std()
z1 = condition2_colA['D'][condition1_colA['D'] < 0].count()
```

Then we would do the same for the other 2 pairs. And organize the 18 calculations on a datframe. I know how to do this manually, but I'm hoping for some help doing it with groupby or perhaps pivot table.

Thanks

Comment: @unutbu Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Now is corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1], [3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4],
     [4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5], [5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1]],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

result = []
pairs = []
for col1, col2 in zip(list('ABC'), list('DEF')):
    pairs.append(col1+col2)
    mask = A[col1] > 1
    mask2 = mask & (A[col2] > 0)
    ser = A.loc[mask, col2]
    result.append((ser.mean(), ser.std(), mask2.sum()))

    mask = A[col1] < 1
    mask2 = mask & (A[col2] < 0)
    ser = A.loc[mask, col2]
    result.append((ser.mean(), ser.std(), mask2.sum()))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pairs, [1, 2]], names=['pair', 'cond'])
df = pd.DataFrame(result, index=index, columns=['mean', 'sum', 'count'])
print(df)
```

yields

```
           mean       sum  count
pair cond                       
AD   1     3.00  1.414214      4
     2      NaN       NaN      0
BE   1     4.75  0.500000      4
     2      NaN       NaN      0
CF   1     2.00  2.000000      4
     2      NaN       NaN      0
```

Comment: This does exaclty what I want. Thanks. My only question is, what about the task makes it not doable with groupby or pivot?

Comment: If `cond1` were the negation of `cond2`, then groupby could be used to a limited extent: `A.groupby(A['A'] > 1)['D'].agg(['mean','std','count'])` but here the count is not quite right since it does not further subselect only those rows where `D` is positive. Even if we could surmount that challenge, then we'd still have to arrange for the pairing of the columns. The pairing of the columns is not something that can be naturally expressed using groupby or pivot. So all-in-all, it seemed likely to me that we'd do better using a plain old loop.